# Mirror model in editmode without breaking UVs?

Tags: uv, mirror

Basically the title. Blender breaks up the UVs when doing a ctrl+m in editmode. Anyone know of a plugin or perhaps a script that allows doing this without messing up? I know you can detach, mirror and then rejoin, but with multiple small objects needing to be mirrored in different directions it can be annoying.

-Cheers

[image: The issue]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be a fixed bug (T80623 https://developer.blender.org/T80623) already on the list for potential candidate 2.90.1 https://developer.blender.org/T80396

As a workaround you can use the mirror-modifier and apply it.

Comment: Ah, thats super nice. AFAIK The mirror modifier unfortunately isn't very useful for mirroring/flipping parts of a mesh.

Comment: Ah yes thats true. Dont want to guess how compartmentalized your object is. I didnt test 2.91 experimental yet, hopefully its fixed, maybe its stable enough. Older experimental releases often worked for me! Good luck :)